# How to proper ommit UnboundLocalError: Local variable '' referenced before assignment when exception has been thrown?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

Function a() and b() can throw an exception. This code does not handle while exception is throwing during the assignment "UnboundLocalError: Local variable 'x' referenced before assignment"
Code:

```
def foo():
    try:
        x = a('test')
        b(x, 'test2')
    except Exception as ex:
        raise Exception('Message error: ' + str(x) + " " + str(ex)) #here could be UnboundLocalError: Local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

My solution is:

```
def foo():
    try:
        x = a('test')
        try:
            b(x, 'test2')
        except Exception as ex:
            raise Exception('Message error: ' + str(x) + " " + str(ex))         
    except Exception as ex:
        raise Exception('Message error: ' + str(ex))
```

Is it possible to do it more tricky, elegant? Now I`m forced to use double try except template.

Comment: Why do you need to reference `x` in the exception message in the first place?

Comment: Also, it's not a good idea to have two functions bundled into a catch-all exception like you wanted in first block (or use a blanket `except` in general). Did `x = a('test')` fail or `b(x, 'test2')`? Currently your way of deciphering that is by raising yet another exception that is uncaught.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably one way you could do it:

```
try:
    x = a('test')
    b(x, 'test2')
except Exception as ex:
    if not 'x' in locals():
        x = 'undefined'
    raise Exception('Message error: ' + str(x) + " " + str(ex))
```

Personally, I think catching both exceptions in separate try/except blocks is more elegant, as it shows the reader that a() did not successfully complete and disallows an UnboundLocalError which masks the real issue:

```
try:
    x = a('test')
except Exception as ex:
   raise Exception('oh no, a() failed')
try:
    b(x, 'test2')
except Exception as ex:
    raise Exception('oops, b() failed')
```

Here is some documentation about `locals()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals

Comment: But the logic of the flow doesn't make sense. If `x = a('test')` fails then `b(x, 'test2')` is clearly impossible, so why have it in the same `try`? Just have two separate `try`/`except`, one for each, and have done with it. There's nothing fancy or pythonic about nesting exceptions like this...

Comment: You're right, I wasn't clear in my response. This is what I meant by "catching both exceptions." Although, then an UnboundLocalError wouldn't even be raised. Edited with a better strategy.

Comment: Much better :) Looks less impressive than nesting but makes a whole lot more sense!

Comment: No, you should use the `try ... except ... else` clause.

Comment: That works too. Then you still have something that looks like nested exceptions though, which the poster was trying to avoid.

Comment: @laurent why do you say that? I disagree, i see no benefit at all from that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `else` clause of [[Python]: The try statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement):

```
def foo():
    try:
        x = a("test")
    except Exception as ex:
        raise Exception("Message error (a): " + str(ex))
    else:
        try:
            b(x, "test2")
        except Exception as ex:
            raise Exception("Message error (b): " + str(x) + " " + str(ex))
```